# Why 2 linux processes of same file cannot share text segment?

Tags: linux

I am going through linux processes and I got the following doubt.

if I execute the same program twice from different shells, 2 processes will be created. I always felt that the text segment will be shared by those 2 processes. But some internet pages suggested that the text segment won't be shared between the processes. Can any one please let me know why it can't be shared between different processes?

Comment: @shekharsuman : I am having hard time to co-relate your comment to the question asked :)

Comment: @kadina thanks, I thought it was just me.

Comment: @kadina-Leave that, at least you got what you wanted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern OSes like Linux and Windows processes are all walled down into their own sandbox by definition. There are shared libraries (so/dll) that are deduplicated by the OS, but they only share the code, no storage memory whatsoever. When a process tries to access memory outside its own process space, the MMU (Memory Management Unit) part of the CPU will generate a hard signal, which will terminate the process if not caught or handled explicitly. In Linux this is called a 'segmentation fault' or segfault, in Windows it's an 'access violation'.

To establish inter-process communication (IPC) a program has to actively initiate this, through synchronization objects and methods, like anonymous/named pipes, memory mapped files, signals, semaphores and a whole lot more depending on the OS.